# Home directory issue on two different machines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, administrator, nfs

I am accessing two Linux systems (Ubuntu) with the same username (let’s say `userU`) and password, let’s say their names are *system1* and *system2*. If I change my password on one system it is also effective on the other one. On both systems, `env` outputs `HOME` as:

```
  /globalMachine/u/userU
```

When I enter system1 and type `pwd` it shows:

```
  /globalMachine/u/userU
```

But when I enter system2 it locates me to `/` and says:

```
  could not chdir to home directory /globalMachine/u/userU: Permission denied
  -bash: /globalMachine/u/userU/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

If I type `pwd`, it shows `/`. But, I have `/home/userU` on system2 and it never locates me there. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: If your home directory is `/globalMachine/u/userU` what is `/home/userU`? Also, what are the permissions of `/globalMachine/u/userU` on both machines?

Comment: @terdon on system1 it is "d-wx------". and when i try "ls -la /globalMachines/u/userU" on system2 it says "permissions denied.". thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you are trying to do here. You are mentioning both /home/userU and /globalmachine/u/userU, please explain clearly what each is and also include ls -l output of /home and /globalmachine/u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changed my home directory on the system2:

```
usermod -d /home/userU userU
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just because the password and username is the same doesn't mean your userid is the same. That would be cause permission denied. If you use root on your system2 and then provide the output from an "ls -al" command on userU home directory, it will shed more light onto your issue.

Comment: I typed id on both systems. uid, gid,and groups are all the same...

Comment: also when I enter the /home/userU on system2 and type ls -al, it is empty...